# Display live Current Date and Time on the Form's Title bar?

Tags: vb.net

How can I display the live date and time on the title bar of the user form?

Comment: Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question is not clear and I have voted to close it, but my best guess would be you are trying to do something like this : 
(Edited the question by re-phrasing it)

---

Add a Timer component on your form. Then Start the timer when the form loads. In the Timer's tick event, keep updating the form's title bar with formatted string.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Me.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot. Could you me please help me out to change the question in the form that anyone could understand the problem statement clearly ?